# Pushing a pointer into the eax and ebx registers in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I need to push a pointer into the eax and another into the ebx register. I first solved this with:

```
register int eax asm("eax");
register int ebx asm("ebx");
int main()
{
     eax = ptr1;
     ebx = ptr2;
}
```

Which worked like a charm. However, when I added this into my other code, I got some strange errors about gcc being unable to find a register to spill in class AREG, in totally unrelated part of the code. I googled, and it turns out to actually be a bug in gcc -.-. So, I need an other way, to push two pointers, into the eax and ebx registers. Anyone any ideas?

### Edit:

Since people have been asking what I am trying to accomplish here, I thought I'd explain a bit.

I need to change the eax and ebx for some assembly code I'm trying to run in my program. I need to execute this assembly code, and give a pointer to the parameter via the eax and ebx register. I execute the assembly code by pushing a pointer to it in ebx and that call ebx. When I don't call the register stuff globally, but locally, the assembly code crashes. If I call it globally, I get this weird error at the end of a random function. When I remove that functions, it throws the same error at another random function. Until I ran out of functions, then it works, but then I miss the rest of the code :P

Comment: Remember that EAX is used for return values. And also that it's only 32 bits so you can't store a pointer in EAX on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: @joachimPileborg that's okay, it's a 32bit exe. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: "I googled, and it turns out to actually be a bug in gcc" -- No, it almost certainly isn't. There may be bugs where that error message is generated when it shouldn't be, but that doesn't mean every time you get that error message, it's a compiler bug. Sometimes the error is valid and the error message hints to what's wrong in your code.

Comment: Are you trying to globally allocate those registers to contain the two pointers?  Why?

Comment: Also you should at least point to the place where the statement about the "bug in gcc" is made. Binding physical register to `register` declared objects is not C but an extension of gcc. So speaking of a bug where there is not much formal specification of what this is supposed to do is a bit far fetched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have (inline) assembly code that requires specific parameters in `EAX`/`EBX`, the way to do this in gcc is to use the following:

```
__asm__("transmogrify %0, %1\n" : "+a"(val_for_eax), "+b"(val_for_ebx));
```

This uses what gcc calls inline assembly *constraints* which tell the compiler that the assembly code - whatever it is - expects `val_for_eax`/`val_for_ebx` in `EAX`/`EBX` (that's the `a`/`b` part) as well as that it will return potentially modified versions of these variables (that's the `+`) in these registers as well.

Beyond that, the actual code within the `asm()` statement doesn't matter to the compiler - it'll only need/want to know where the parameters `%0` and `%1` live. The above example will, due to a `transmogrify` instruction not existing in the current x86 instruction set, fail when the assembler runs; just substitute it with something valid.

The explanations why gcc behaves this way and exactly what you can tell it to do is in the GCC manual, at:

- [Extended Assembly - Assembler Instructions with C operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)
- [Constraints for `asm` operands](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html), in particular the Intel/386 section of the [Machine-specific Constraints list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) for what to say if you need to pass/retrieve a value in a specific register, and the [Modifiers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) section about the meaning of things like the `+` (to both pass and return a value; there are other such "modifiers" to the constraints)

You can specify a specific register for a variable but due to the way gcc works / the way inline assembly is implemented in gcc, doing so *does not mean* (!) the register is from then on *reserved* (out of scope) for gcc to use for its own purposes. That can only be achieved through constraints, for a specific, single `asm()` block - the constraints tells gcc what to write into those registers *before* the placement of the actual assembly code, and what to read from them *afterwards*.

Comment: Hhm gcc style assembly is weird, ohwell, after messing around with this a litle bit it works!

Answer (score 4):

Since the `eax` register is need all over the place in a valid program on your architecture, your strategy can't work with global variables that are bound to the specific registers. Don't do that, reserving a register globally is not a good idea.

Place the variables that are bound to registers in the particular function, as close as possible to their use.

Comment: I tried this, changing them from global to local variables, but then it just doesn't work.

Comment: You'd have to explain better what the problem is, what your code tries to achieve etc. "just doesn't work" is not very constructive.

Comment: I need to change the eax and ebx for some assembly code im trying to run in my program. I need to execute this assembly code, and give a pointer to the parameter via the eax and ebx register. I execute the assembly code by pushing a pointer to it in ebx and that call ebx.